# How make memtest save more than 10 errors in report?

Tags: memtest86+

I am running [memtest](https://www.memtest86.com/) and got html report at the end. But it contains only last 10 memory errors while I have a bit more. Is there a way to set up memtest to save say 1000 error in report?

Comment: You have enough errors to replace the memory.

Comment: yes, and I plan to do so. But I need all errors (for excluding) to live with current memory for some period of time

Comment: That limit of 10 errors is really ridiculous. Did you find a solution?